# Component-preload.js not found though it exists

Tags: sapui5

I am getting component-preload.js not found error even tough it exists..

I'm using SAP WEBIDE personal edition full stack. so, neo-app.js and package.json are generated by defalut and by using the **build** option I generated component.-preload.js along with dist folder.As in my project I dont have direct connection to the SAP system,I need to use export(from webide) and import/download(using UI5/UI5/REPOSITORY_LOAD) into my front end server.Once I upload the project into the front end server component-preload.js is missing so am getting the same error "Component-preload.js missing" even though it exists.

could some one please let me know what could be the problem and how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post a screenshot of the error, also the Component.js

Comment: Did you try to check in se80 transaction whether this file was really there?

Comment: Does component.js exist? I only seem to get this error when this is missing.

Comment: Hi, Can you please let me know, How was this resolved?